# Unable to Boot Ubuntu OS of Cloned VM

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vmware, clone

Using VMware version 5.5.0, I cloned a virtual machine running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64). Prior to powering on the cloned machine, I disconnected it from network adapters. After powering it on, the OS fails to complete initialization. The following messages appear:

[image: Boot process log messages]

After that, a blinking cursor (_) appears indefinitely.
How can I resolve this issue? Once I'm able to boot into the OS, I would like to be able to change the network settings so that it doesn't conflict with the original machine (i.e. the machine from which it was cloned).

Comment: Try removing any `quiet` and similar parameters from the kernel command line, and see if you get more detailed error output. Modern distributions usually boot in quiet mode; in non-quiet mode, the kernel is much more verbose, and this can be a highly useful debugging aid. In this particular case, my first suspect would be loadable modules, but it's hard to say based on only what you have provided.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to remove quiet and similar parameters from the kernel command line? I have access only to the GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9 command line interface and the ability to edit commands before booting.

Comment: I do not believe the quiet parameter is being used. Here's the kernel commands: `linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=IIOD=482030f0-8501-42df-9d20-ffffffff ro' followed by `initrd /boot/initrd.mg-3.13.0-24-generic`. Unfortunately, I have no ability to copy from my console window and I do not have enough reputation point on superuser to post screenshots (i.e. images). So, I have to manually type the log messages. I can add more messages in the OP if that is needed although they don't seem to be error messages.

Comment: If you feel images will make your question easier to understand or answer, just post them anywhere and include a link in your question. Someone will edit them in properly. Indeed it looks like your kernel is not being booted with the `quiet` parameter.